# PHP form does not POST content back

Tags: php, html

There were plenty question like mine. I know. I read them all. Still got no working script. Problem is simple, I want to create script with simple form which will refer to itself and I want to be able to get passed through form variables. here is my code:

```
<?
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

after first call i should get `array(0){}` printed with `var_dump` function but after first click on `submit` button `$_POST` array should get filled, meanwhile i still got empty array.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your action is empty?

Comment: yup I want to refere to the same page

Comment: then you need to put the ref of the same page into action? :)

Comment: for me its working like this (from chrome and ff)

Comment: when i insert mine script name i sill got an empty array

Comment: short tag <? can sometime cause problem(in some browsers).

Comment: Do you use exact same code as in question? probably you have something else, because this code works great. Do you have `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Do any of your other forms work? As Narek says, the .htaccess file and routing rules can strip the post data if set up incorrectly.

Comment: @Narek yes this is exacly same code. i have ever use `.htaccess` where i should look for it?

Comment: @Mithrand1r no if you didn't add it then problem in other place. Remove all code and put just `<?php phpinfo()?>` and let us know does it print PHP info or not.

Comment: have you tried just adding full php tag (<?php ) at beggining? so that you dont go over more advanced stuff if it is simple.

Comment: Im beginier in this field but please stop asking if `<?php` tag would work

Comment: @Narek i got full `phpinfo` as it should be, Want he to post it?

Comment: i am just saying dont use short tags. Maybe in this case it will not solve your problem though your example did not work on my chrome with short tags.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic short tag is **PHP** option so it **not depend on** browser.

Comment: @Mithrand1r I just want to be sure what your PHP works, and it is. This is very strange error.

Comment: funfact: when i change form method to `get` variable `$_GET` is being set just fine but i really need my data to be posted..

Comment: have you tried setting enctype="multipart/form-data" in form?

Comment: i did, same empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<html>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in action, will make it into the page name of the page you are on.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Submit'){
    var_dump($_POST);
}else{
?>
<html>
<body>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit" name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would explicitly state in the form that it should be posting to itself:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
```

Submitting the form then results it the $_POST variable being populated with the values from the form.

Answer (score 0):

I can see no reason why it would behave this way - you're going to have to solve this yourself.

But I'm adding an answer because you seem to be stuck as to hopw to progress this.

1) look at your webserver log file - is your POST getting to the server and being processed?

2) what happens when you change the method to get?

3) are there other scripts on the server working as expected? If not then how / what was installed?

(BTW even though it's just debugging / experimenting, try to make your HTML well formed)

Comment: Where i can find logs which will have post requests?

Comment: I don't know - you've not told us anything about where you got the softwarte from, how it's configured nor even what OS it's running on. (might be /var/logs/httpd)

Answer (score 0):

Invalid HTML might be the issue here. Some browser fix invalid html but not all. Close the input tags and try then. If not then let me know

```
<form action="<!-- add the script name here. Dont leave blank eg. form.php-->" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname"/>
Age: <input type="text" name="age"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this out

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
?>
<form name="test" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="my_test" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```